# AngularJS not finding values in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a AngularJS app developed.

On a view I have a list of items - each with its own set of radio buttons. The list and buttons are built at run-time from an API call.

Both the list and radio buttons can be of any length e.g. list item 1 might contain 3 radio buttons while list item n might contain 2 radio buttons.

When the user selects a radio button I fire a ng-click method that sends both the list ID as well as the radio button ID to the controller.

The view looks as follows and I have tested this and the values are being sent to the controller.

```
<label class="radio-button" ng-repeat="option in checkItemDescription.options">
    <input type="radio" name="option_question_id_{{checkItemDescription.fleetcheckitemid}}" 
                            ng-model="checkItemDescription.selected_id"
                            ng-click="doSomething(checkItemDescription.fleetcheckitemid, option.fleetcheckid)"
                            ng-value="option.fleetcheckid">
    <div class="radio-button__checkmark"></div>
    Description: {{option.checkvaluedesc}}
</label>
```

In my doSomething() method i am trying to see if either the *checkItemDescription.fleetcheckitemid* or the *option.fleetcheckid* id is in a existing array.

I use indexOf() method to compare the values but the method does not seem to work - even though console.log() shows values are sent to the controller.

Below is my doSomething() method.

```
$scope.doSomething = function(fleetCheckItemID, fleetCheckID)
{
    if ( $scope.initialFleetCheckIssueItemIDArray.indexOf(fleetCheckItemID))
    {
        console.log("Yeah!"); // Never gets to here even though logs show values exist
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Ah!"); // Always get here
    }
}
```

What I need to do is to to create a JSON object with the list item ID, radio button ID and some other values e.g. date/time based on the user selection to send to my Database.

Is this the best way to do it or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

-referenced from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

so if your element is first in the collection then indexOf would return 0 which would result in the execution of else block so change your if condition like this.

```
if ( $scope.initialFleetCheckIssueItemIDArray.indexOf(fleetCheckItemID) != -1 )
{
    //element found, do stuff here.
}
else
{
    //element does not found, else stuff here.
}
```